# Apache2 + OpenSSL, Certificate CA

Tags: apache2, openssl, certificate

I've created the self-signed server certificate, the private server key and the Certificate Authority's own certificate using the below commands.

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -config openssl.cnf -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -config openssl.cnf -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt
```

I've then added them to httpd-ssl.conf using the below.

```
SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache2/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache2/conf/server.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/Apache2/conf/ca.crt"
```

However when visiting https://localhost I get:-

> Secure Connection Failed An error occurred during a connection to
>   localhost. Peer's certificate has an invalid signature. (Error code:
>   sec_error_bad_signature) The page you are trying to view can not be
>   shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be
>   verified.
>   * Please contact the web site owners to inform them of this problem.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks

**Normal untrusted error**
localhost uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because it is self signed.

**My CA certificate error**
An error occurred during a connection to localhost.
Peer's certificate has an invalid signature.

Comment: What common name (CN) did you use when you generated your certificate ?

Comment: For both the server and ca I used localhost

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try re-generating your certificate this way:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

Then, remove the passphrase from the server certificate for avoiding Apache asking you the password everytime you restart it:

```
cp server.key server.key.org
openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key
```

And then, generate your self-signed certificate

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

After, just specify `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` to use your new certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Because self signed certificates don't have a trusted root certificate authority you need to add them to the the browser's trusted CA list. A browser cannot verify an untrused certificate.

Comment: I think my error may be a configuration one as opposed to my certificate being self signed. I've never used SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/Apache2/conf/ca.crt" for self signed certificates, but if I don't use ca.crt and generate a non-ca crt it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it's a self signed certificate. To avoid this message, you'll need to get yourself verified and buy a certificate from trusted CA authority like Verisign, GoDaddy,etc.
You can also try the free certificate from [COMODO Instant SSL](http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/free-ssl-certificate.html?key5sk1=999ce9ab1995c970cbc4ae3bd79dd45c94f330cb&key5sk2=&key5sk3=1332870040000&key5sk4=&key5sk5=1332870045000&key5sk6=&key5sk7=1332870156000&key5sk8=&key5sk9=1332870162000&key6sk1=&key6sk2=CH17096383&key6sk3=7&key6sk4=en-us&key6sk5=IN&key6sk6=0&key6sk7=Google&key6sk8=111102&key6sk9=1600900&key6sk10=true&key6sk11=&key7sk1=0000&key7sk2=0000&key7sk3=0000&key7sk4=0000)

Since you're just testing on localhost, don't worry about the warning. But on production, this might deter away your users.

Comment: Normaly on a non-CA untrusted certificate I get the Error code: sec_error_untrusted_issuer but Error code: sec_error_bad_signature does not allow me to add an exception. Can you see if I have made a configuration error?